# Problems with '\rightrightarrows' and other a arrow symbols

Tags: symbols, packages, arrows

I'm trying to define a mathematical correspondence.  The double-arrow symbol is supposed to be `\rightrightarrows`. But when I run it LaTex tells me that it is not defined.  This also happens with other arrow symbols (like `\circlearrowleft`) that are supposed to be available.

Can anyone help me? Do you know if I need a package for those symbols?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: ,@JesúsSantxezIbrahim -- Yes, you need to load `amssymb` package

Comment: Isn't it `\leftrightarrow`?

Comment: The double arrow, if I understand well, is `\Rightarrow`. `\circlearrowleft` comes with `amsfonts` or `amssymb`.

Comment: @Bernard I assumed <-> was intended rather than =>, but you might be correct.

Comment: @cfr: I've just checked, the O.P. probably meant two arrows, one above the other. I think it comes with `amssymb`.

Comment: There is a symbol \rightrightarrows in amssymb as @AboAmmar mentioned.

Comment: @JPi: I beat you by **3** seconds!

Comment: Right, @AboAmmar should provide an answer like:   \documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}


\begin{document}
 $\rightrightarrows$
\end{document}

Comment: @Bernard: Indeed, you did.

Comment: Ha, but I'm the first to +1 the question! ;-)

Comment: @JPi: The point is not that I beat you – I don't care to beat any one  – but the 3 seconds…

Comment: Yes, that is impressive,

Answer (score 7):

Finding a particular LaTeX symbol or character can be very easy. Have a look at “[**How to look up a math symbol?**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/59109)” for ideas on how you can achieve this. The linked question lists two especially helpful tools; namely the [**Comprehensive LaTeX symbols**](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) list and a web-based software known as [**Detexify**](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html). The latter is also available for smart phones.

If you try one of the above tools, you will discover that the symbols you need require using the `amssymb` package. Here are some examples:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\begin{document} 

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
$\circlearrowleft$  & $\leftleftarrows$      & $\rightleftarrows$     \\
$\circlearrowright$ & $\leftrightarrows$     & $\rightrightarrows$    \\
$\curvearrowleft$   & $\leftrightsquigarrow$ & $\rightsquigarrow$     \\
$\curvearrowright$  & $\Lleftarrow$          & $\Rsh$                 \\
$\dashleftarrow$    & $\looparrowleft$       & $\twoheadleftarrow$    \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]